# Implementing a general switch statement in Java

Tags: java, swing, switch-statement, jslider

I have a JSlider with values from 1 to 360. For each value I want to get an image from a database and put it to a JLabel. So I have 360 cases where the single difference is the variable switch used to get the corresponding image from database (see bellow code). I know that I need to refresh my code because with my "solution" the code it is very heavy.

I hope that I was clear what I want to archive. Bellow is the code.

```
degreesSlider = new JSlider(); //my JSlider

degreesSlider.setMajorTickSpacing(10);
degreesSlider.setMaximum(360);
degreesSlider.setMinorTickSpacing(1);
degreesSlider.setOrientation(javax.swing.JSlider.VERTICAL);
degreesSlider.setPaintLabels(true);
degreesSlider.setPaintTicks(true);
degreesSlider.setSnapToTicks(true);
degreesSlider.setValue(0);

degreesSlider.addChangeListener(new ChangeListener() {
            public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent evt) {

                int x = degreesSlider.getValue(); //get JSlider value

                int row = myJTable.getSelectedRow();
                int realIndex = myJTable.convertRowIndexToModel(row);
                String clickJTable = (myJTable.getModel().getValueAt(realIndex, 0).toString()); //detect my JTable row click

                switch (x) {

                    case 1:
                        try {
                            PreparedStatement pst = conn.prepareStatement("select pol, cros from test where degrees = ? AND id_min=?");
                            pst.setInt(1, x); //x is the only variable of the all 360 cases
                            pst.setString(2, clickJTable);
                            ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery();

                            if (rs.next()) {
                                byte[] imageP = rs.getBytes("pol");
                                byte[] imageC = rs.getBytes("cros");

                                pol = new ImageIcon(imagepolars);
                                cros = new ImageIcon(imagecrossed);

                                mineralsPolars.setIcon(pol); //put image into JLabel
                                mineralsCrossed.setIcon(cros); //put image into JLabel
                            }
                            rs.close();
                            pst.close();
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                        }
                        break;

                    //case 2, 3, 4 ... 360 with the same code and the difference between them is the variable x


                }

            }
        });
```

Comment: It's not clear what the difference is meant to be - you say "the difference between them is the variable x" but your `pst.setInt(1, x);` already does that...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Considering the code for each of the switch clauses is the same, why don't you replace your switch with

```
 if (x >= 1 && x <= 360) {
     // do the db lookup
 }
```

EDIT:

The only reason you need the if statement is if you want to check that the slider value (`x`) is in the same range as specified by your query, and as @NominSim pointed out, the slider values are in your control, so you may not need that if at all.

Comment: @NominSim: which is what this would do, the `x` value has already been read from the slider, so the lookup code can use that `x` value, do the DB lookup and then update the `mineralPolar` and `mineralCrossed` JLabel.  The reason why this is guarded by an `if` block is because his code would only do the DB lookup for values `1..360`, which is exactly what the if does.

Comment: @NominSim: which makes the downvote a bit harsh, don't you think?

Comment: @To all: I didn't considered to use a `for` statement because I started with switch didn't take into account the large number of situations. That was so easy but for me so ambiguous due to the large amount of code. Thanks to all, and today I learned again that less is more :).

Answer (score 2):

From what I understand you do not need a `switch` statement, you need only a function that will retrieve and update the icon with the proper icon, based on the slider value. Since the code that retrieves and updates the icon is based only on your `x` value, that will be passed to the new function. 
To improve the performance of such a function you can move the creation of the prepared statement object outside of this function. Since creating a prepared statement object for each call will cancel almost all the benefits of a prepared statement and it's very costly to build  such a heavy object on each call/slider value change.

I recommand using a [DAO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_access_object) object to encapsulate your db logic in one place and not pollute the UI code with SQL and db logic. This way you will be able to achieve better performance by reusing the already created statements and reuse the code.

Answer (score 1):

> Each case value must be a compile time constant/expression, not a
>   variable. No two of the case constant expressions associated with a
>   switch statement may have the same value.

what you can have is call a subroutine with selected value

something like `changeLabelImgTo(int count);`

Answer (score 0):

Extract your code into a method and pass in the variable `x`:

```
public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent evt) {
    ...
    fetchImage(x);
    ...
}


private void fetchImage(int x) {

    try {
        PreparedStatement pst = conn.prepareStatement("select pol, cros from test where degrees = ? AND id_min=?");
        pst.setInt(1, x); //x is the only variable of the all 360 cases
        pst.setString(2, clickJTable);
        ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery();

        if (rs.next()) {
            byte[] imageP = rs.getBytes("pol");
            byte[] imageC = rs.getBytes("cros");

            pol = new ImageIcon(imagepolars);
            cros = new ImageIcon(imagecrossed);

            mineralsPolars.setIcon(pol); //put image into JLabel
            mineralsCrossed.setIcon(cros); //put image into JLabel
        }
        rs.close();
        pst.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I may be missing something here, but if the code blocks inside case are all the same, why are you using a switch case, after all?